# Regex How to ignore only one url type

Tags: regex

I have a problem, where I can't allow a word + any type of url, but I want to ignore the text that contains the url hacking.com

```
Valid:   Buy Cell Phone at https://storeOfficial.com
Valid:   Buy Cell Phone at https://store.com
Invalid: Buy Cell Phone at https://hacking.com
Invalid: Buy Cell Phone at https://storeOfficial.com and https://hacking.com
```

My Regex:

```
^(?=[\w\W]*([\W|_]+|^)(Cell Phone\b|cell phone\b|CELL PHONE\b).*(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(?i)^.*\bCell Phone\b(?!.*(?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/(?:[^.]*\.)?hacking\.com(?=\/|$)).*(?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/\S+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lLsCQn/1). *Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive flag on
- `^` - start of a string
- `.*`  - any text
- `\bCell Phone\b` - a whole word `Cell Phone`
- `(?!.*(?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/(?:[^.]*\.)?hacking\.com(?=\/|$))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, then a protocol, then an optional sequence of any zero or more chars other than a `.` char and then a `.` char, and then `hacking.com` string, either at the end of string or immediately followed with a `/` char
- `.*` - any text
- `(?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/\S+` - `http://`, `https://`, `ftps://` or `ftp://` and then one or more non-whitespace chars.